# Google Map is not animating to current location on resuming

Tags: android-maps-v2

This is my main activity, here its working properly, But once after going back if we again load map its not displaying the current location as it does for the first time(i.e when `onCreate()` is called.) GPSTracker file is implementing LocationListner interface and providing me current location which I am passing to goToLocation(lat, lng)

```js
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.before_login_map_activity);
      progressView = (View) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
      if (initMap()) {
        gpsTracker = new GPSTracker(this);
        if (gpsTracker.canGetLoaction()) {
          originlon = gpsTracker.getLongitide();
          originlat = gpsTracker.getLattitude();
          mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
          mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
          goToLocatoin(originlat, originlon);
        }
        getJsonLatLon();
      } else {
        Toast.makeText(BeforeLoginMapActivity.this, "Map Not Available!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
```

```html
<fragment android:id="@+id/map" android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" tools:ignore="MissingPrefix" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: why don't you simply move your implementation to `onResume`?

Comment: Thank you Androiderson, for you help, but I used CameraPosition class and it worked for me. Providing the code below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1)Declare a private CameraPosition variable
2)Then override onPause() and from GoogleMap instance getCameraPosition
3)Again override onResume() to GoogleMap instace provide CameraPosition

```js
//Globally declare CameraPosition
private CameraPosition cp;


@Override
protected void onPause() {
  super.onPause();
  cp = mMap.getCameraPosition();
  mMap = null;
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
  super.onResume();
  if (cp != null) {
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cp));
    cp = null;
  }
}
```